# node-postgresql db connection deprecated

Tags: postgresql

I am using node-v8.9.1-x64. & postgresql-10.1-2. I have tried running this code but its gives an error "code deprecated" and even tried some other ways. It still comes back with new errors

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
       // PG connect -code deprecated
      pg.connect(connect, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool', err);
        }
      client.query('SELECT * FROM books', function(err, result) {
        if(err) {
            return console.error('error running query', err);
        }
        res.render('index', {books: result.rows});
        done();
        });
     
    });
```

I went through the documentation but I am not getting  it. Please somebody help me.

Comment: You should see if there are any functions you are calling that are in [this article](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. but i see no such function in the list.